# Why isn't my meteor {{#each}} working?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor app at [whensayfeed.meteor.com](http://whensayfeed.meteor.com). It's supposed to repeat this div and it's contents for each document in a mongo collection, but it doesn't work. It used to. I can't seem to figure it out. My code is [here](https://github.com/zeekw/WhenISayMobileFeed) on github. If you would mind looking it over that would be incredible.

**HTML**

```
<template name="FullFeed">
  {{#each posts}}
    <div class="post-contain">
      <div class="chant">{{adjective}} {{noun}}</div>
      <div class="author-box"><p>{{user}}</p></div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #0F76D2;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.post-contain {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 230px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #0F76D2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.author-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.42);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.author-box p {
  position: relative;
}

.author-box > p { margin: 0 }
.author-box { padding: 10px 0 }

.chant {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.chant .varline {
  color: #3f3f3f;
}
```

**JS**

```
posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('FullFeed', {
    data: function () {  }
  });
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.FullFeed.helpers({
    posts: posts.find({}).fetch()
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the `posts` helper declaration, you're declaring it once and for all as an array (using `Cursor.fetch`) when your application code is first executed.

Your helper must be declared as a function if you want it to get reactively re-executed whenever the underlying cursor is modified, and you don't need to use `fetch`, Meteor `{{#each}}` block is optimized for cursors.

```
Template.FullFeed.helpers({
  posts: function(){
    return posts.find();
  }
});
```